# Some questions about prime number research

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, advice

I'm an undergraduate who is studying for determination of prime number with my academic advisor.
Before I meet her, I want to prepare more hardly. So, I'd like to ask you some questions that I'm most curious about.

> 1. In number theory sense, are the terminologies 'primorial' and 'primality' used? (primorial is the product prime numbers $p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n$ where $p_i$ is the $i-$th prime number.)

If I can use the terminology primality, my study is about the condition when given integer is prime number. I'm reading some books:

[1] G.H. Hardy and E.M. Wright, An introduction to the theory of numbers, 6th edn., Oxford University Press, 2008.

[2] J.V. Uspensky and M.A. Heaslet, Elementary Number Theory, New York: McGraw Hill, 1939.

[3] W. Narkiewicz, The Development of Prime Number Theory, New York: Springer-Verlag, 2000.

> 2. About reference, I could only find papers in computer science. But I want to read the papers in number theory. How can I find? Or, is there any recommended paper or book?

Thanks.

Comment: o.t.: Maybe I am wrong, but using "terminology" for a singel word sounds strange to me. Maybe "term" is more appropriate.

Comment: For a modern account, see the book *Prime Numbers: A Computational Perspective* by Crandall and Pomerance.

Comment: @miracle173 You are right. According to the definition, 'terminology' is used for a set. I'll be careful from now.

Comment: @AnginaSeng The book you recommended is exactly what I was looking for.More than half of the books are closely related to my research subjects.Thank you very much.If I have any questions about this book later, can I contact you again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Question 1*: Yes, primorial is used, see [wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial). And also yes, primality is used, but *prime element* or *prime number* is used more often, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element).

*Question 2*: The literature given is excellent and not from computer science. To search for papers makes more sense when you have a more specific topic, e.g., the prime number theorem, or the Riemann hypothesis and so on.

*Question 3*: "How can I find it?" You can always search yourself with key words. I obtain $ 28 600 000$ search hits for "Prime Number Theorem". Usually the first $10$ hits are already quite helpful.

Comment: I knew that the books I mentioned were about number theory. But all the papers I found in google are covered in the computer field. These are good papers too, but what I'm most curious about is grammar in number theory. Thank you for your sincere advice on trivial questions.